# Memory consumption of a dictionary: set a value None vs. delete the item

Tags: python

I understand that `del d[key]` will delete the key-value pair, whereas `d[key]=None` only de-references the value.

However, in terms of memory management, is there any difference? Does setting a value `None` trigger garbage collection immediately, assuming that there is no other variable referencing this value?

I ran a little experiment:

```
In [74]: import sys
In [75]: a = {'a': 'blah'}

In [76]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[76]: 280

In [77]: a['a'] = None

In [79]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[79]: 280

In [80]: del a['a']

In [81]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[81]: 280
```

Not sure if the approach is valid, but it seems no difference in terms of the size of the dictionary at all. I must miss something here.

Comment: Having a ``None`` value still means the dictionary has to have a reference to the key linked to a reference to the ``None``, deleting the value will remove it from the dict entirely. They are completely different operations, and are in no way equivalent.

Comment: A `dict` object includes `smalltable` for up to 5 items (sized for 8 entries, but it can only be 2/3 full). The table grows in powers of 2, starting at 8. On a 32-bit system a `PyDictEntry` is 12 bytes, so the `smalltable` is 96 bytes, plus 28 bytes in othe fields, coming to 124 bytes. `sys.getsizeof` also reports the 12 bytes prepended to the dict for GC tracking (`gc_next`, `gc_prev`, `gc_refs`), making the total size 136 bytes. The GC handles reference cycles that would prevent unreachable containers (e.g. dicts, classes) from being deallocated.

Comment: @Lattyware: The OP wasn't saying they are equivalent, he was saying that `d[key]=None` dereferences the value, which is true.

Comment: Also, the table is resized when items are set or you do an `update`, if it's more than 2/3 full with active plus dummy keys (open addressing scheme). Deleting a key only marks it as a 'dummy'; it doesn't resize the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof` measures the size of the dict itself; not the size of the values it contains.

`None` is an object. It requires some memory.

To find the size of a dict *including* the size of the values it contains, you could use [pympler](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/):

```
In [26]: import pympler.asizeof as asizeof

In [27]: asizeof.asizeof({'a': None})
Out[27]: 168

In [28]: asizeof.asizeof({})
Out[28]: 136

In [29]: import sys

In [30]: 
In [31]: sys.getsizeof({})
Out[31]: 136

In [34]: sys.getsizeof({'a':None})
Out[34]: 136
```

Comment: thanks! But which will clear up memory faster `del` or set value to `None`? Or that question depends on some other factor?

Comment: "None is an object. It requires some memory." Actually, None is a singleton, so it doesn't require memory itself. Having it in a dictionary does require memory (for the key and for the pointer).

Comment: @MLister As Python is reference counted, both will have the same effect when the reference is lost (either by deleting the key and value, or changing the value to another), if the reference count reaches 0, the garbage collector will clean the memory.

Answer (score 2):

unutbu is correct. But also the python garbage collector can be a little slow on the uptake sometimes.

Calling del on an object and removing all references to that object means that the garbage collector can collect it whenever it feels ready. This will not usually result in an immediate decrease in the amount of memory used.

you can make use of the gc module to force collection and look at what the garbage collector actually sees.

Comment: CPython's garbage collector is reference counted, so under the most popular Python version, it'll free the memory very quickly.

Comment: `gc.collect(generation=2)` can clear out containers that are caught up in reference cycles (e.g. `a.b, b.a = b, a`), but only if they don't have a `__del__` finalizer. If you use `generation=2`, it also clears the `freelist`s used by PyFrame, PyMethod, PyCFunction, PyTuple, PyUnicode, PyInt, and PyFloat. These are lists of allocated objects that can be reused without having to allocate a new object on the heap. Unless you absolutely need the memory back from these freelists, use `gc.collect(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

A python dictionary contains, next to the logic, pointers to all keys and pointers to all values.

- Setting a value to None leaves the number of objects in the dictionary intact, it replaces one value pointer to a pointer to the None object. If the old value object is no longer referenced from elsewhere, it will be garbage collected. The key will stay.
- Deleting a value, if that means the key and/or the value are no longer referenced, will result in cleanup of both, and in principle reduces the size of the dictionary itself. Whether the dictionary will actually "shrink" is an implementation detail I don't know.

Testing this on one object may not be representative. Try a million. Furthermore testing it with a short "string" object may not be representative, because a string may be "interned", i.e. it may become part of the indestructable set of objects that are reused automatically whenever the interpreter needs it again.